# Getting null count for Notesdocumentcollection

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Initially my issue was I'm getting an over flow because the length of the value in the first two fields (IDs) were longer, and back then I'm using Clng (long). I had to change it to Cstr (string).

I have also updated the first two columns in the view @Text(fieldname), and it's still sorted in ascending order.

I have 4 keys, first two of which are from parent form (but I made it also available in the dialog box form), third and fourth key is coming from the dialog box form.

Code snippet could be found below:

```
Set lookupdb = session.GetDatabase(lserver$,ldb$)
Set lookupview = lookupdb.GetView(lview$)

Set dateRange = session.CreateDateRange()
Set dateRange.StartDateTime = dateTime1
Set dateRange.EndDateTime = dateTime2

'Variant because of the daterange in keys (4)
Dim keys( 1 To 4 ) As Variant 

keys(1) = Cstr(uidoc.FieldGetText("FirstID"))
keys(2) = Cstr(uidoc.FieldGetText("SecondID"))
keys(3) = Trim(uidoc.FieldGetText("Station"))
Set keys(4) = daterange

'Test. This has output. For daterange I used .text so I can see output.
Msgbox keys(1)
Msgbox keys (2)
Msgbox keys (3)
Msgbox daterange.text

Set lookupcoll = lookupview.GetAllDocumentsByKey(keys,True)
If lookupcoll.Count <> 0 Then
    Print "Criteria Selection Count : " + Cstr(lookupcoll.count)
    Set lookupdoc = lookupcoll.GetFirstDocument
    ctr = 0
    Do While Not lookupdoc Is Nothing 
        <code here>
    Loop

    Print "Ended : " + Now()


Else
    Messagebox "No Document Retrieved."
End If

Exit Sub
```

I am getting the "No Document Retrieved" and when I checked the documentcollection, it has 0 in it.

Please let me know why I'm getting null. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, have you tried your keys with base 0 instead of base 1 dim keys (0 to 3) and regarding the notes help. keys is string or array of string, not variant. so daterange might be inappropriate

Comment: try to use only one key and if that find documents, add another key. that would help you to identify where the issue happens.

Comment: Agree with Dmytro. Test one key, two keys, three keys, four keys to find out where you start getting zero results And if it is the fourth key, that causes the problem, what exactly is in the view's 4th sorted column, and what are the display options for that column set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GetAllDocumentsByKey method requires that your view, `lookupview`, has the first few columns categorized and sorted by the keys you are using to search it.

From the [docs](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/lotusscript/lotusscript.nsf/1efb1287fc7c27388525642e0074f2b6/d246a1b6fc695ba58525642e0075cdde?OpenDocument):

> **GetAllDocumentsByKey method**
>
> Finds documents based on their column values within a view. You create
> an array of strings (keys), where each key corresponds to a value in a
> sorted and categorized column in the view. The method returns the all
> documents whose column values match each key in the array.

You may need to change your view's design to accommodate the search you are performing.